# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'gfile' even with tensorflow v1

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I am having a problem as i upload my model in drive and mount it in Colab module imports are working fine in previous cell as i gave the root path and sys.append() it , I am using (tf.compat.v1) you can see it in ouptut, but still getting this error also tried (tensorflow v2) and used **tf.io.gfile** but still same error. Kindly help me

```
<module 'tensorflow_core.compat.v1.version' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/_api/v2/compat/v1/version/__init__.py'>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-e851eb463895> in <module>()
      1 print(tf.version)
----> 2 category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index_from_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS, use_display_name=True)

2 frames
/content/drive/My Drive/models/research/object_detection/utils/label_map_util.py in load_labelmap(path)
    136     a StringIntLabelMapProto
    137   """
--> 138   with tf.gfile.GFile(path, 'r') as fid:
    139     label_map_string = fid.read()
    140     label_map = string_int_label_map_pb2.StringIntLabelMap()

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'gfile'
```

Comment: Can you try downgrade to `TF1.15` from `TF2.x` and see if your issue has resolved in your local machine. If you are looking for simple solution for Colab, please use `%tensorflow_version 1.x` magic command, which does for you without un-installation.

Comment: Thanks, for the help I did the same. It worked fine with v1.15. I just import tensorflow.compat.v1 in label_map_util which starts using v1.15 as default.

Comment: I am glad it helped you. If you would have import `import tensorflow as tf`, it will also start use`TF 1.15`. For the benefit of community i will post this as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to downgrade `TF 1.15` from `TF 2.x`, your issue will be resolved.

Please refer code as shown below

```
!pip uninstall tensorflow
!pip install tensorflow==1.15

 import tensorflow as tf
```

If you are looking for simple solution for Colab, please use `%tensorflow_version 1.x` magic command, which does for you without un-installation.

```
%tensorflow_version 1.x
 import tensorflow as tf
```